# Is there any way to generate documentation using appledoc in AppCode?

Tags: objective-c, documentation-generation, appcode, appledoc

Or is there any way (using other docs generators) to make it work in AppCode ?

Comment: You should ask this on the AppCode support form: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/objc

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you! found this one: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-3526

Comment: I have opened a request for a documentation tool in 2012 and so far there is no sign that they will do it: [appcode issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-3526)